# How do you know if a Locust instance is running as master or worker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance-testing, load-testing, locust

This is a simple example of what I want to do.

In would like to run a peace of code only if it is the master.

```py
class SimpleTaskSet(TaskSet):

    @task
    def do_something(self):
        # do something ...
        pass


class MyOwnLocust(Locust):
    task_set = SimpleTaskSet
    min_wait = 1
    max_wait = 10

    def setup(self):
        if master:  # How to here the code is running on master?
            # do something
            pass
        else:
            # do something else
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check if a locust is either a master or a slave, you can use `runners` from locust, then check if the current runner is an instance of Master:

```
from locust import runners

... # Your code

def setup(self):
    if isinstance(runners.locust_runner, runners.MasterLocustRunner):
        # do something
        pass
    else:
        # do something else
        pass
```

However, keep in mind that the Locust Master does not do tasks and will not go through all functions like a Locust Slave.

EDIT - For the second question

From my knowledge, given the way how Locust works, running a piece of code only once for an entire test can be very tricky.

The first thing you can do is use the TaskSet method `setup` as such:

```
class Behavior(TaskSet):
    def setup(self):
        # Do things only once here

    # The rest of your code


class User(HttpLocust):
    task_set = Behavior
    # ....
```

You can read a bit more regarding the setup / on_start / on+stop etc. on the official documentation: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html?highlight=setup#setups-teardowns-on-start-and-on-stop

Now, what's the problem regarding this setup? I don't know what you are trying to achieve in this setup section, but it's very important to remember that this function will run only once per test but it will run only once per process.

What does that mean? If you run a Locust test in distributed mode (master-slave setup), the `setup` function will run once for each python process (a.k.a. for each separate slave terminal you started the test with).

If this is not an issue for you, you can easily go with the setup function for what you are trying to achieve. If not however, you might need to come up with a way for the Locust processes to be aware of each other so that they can check if they need to run the contents of `setup` as well or skip the block because a slave process already ran it. This can get tricky.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @alin-luga, specially for explaining that master will not run it! Do you have/know any example on how I can have  a piece of code executed by only one slave? Or even a possible not tested way I could try?

Comment: Thanks again @aliniuga !
I am aware of the `setup` and `on_start` as per the documentation you referred!
But I really want to create some resource only independent of the number of slaves. I am looking at Locust code and possibly I will achieve this with some custom event hooks between master and slaves.

Answer (score 0):

as per the locust docs https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#test-start-and-test-stop-events, the test_start event will only run on master when running in distributed mode.
the test_start event will occur after the locust init event.
You can also check for the node type using the trick above at the module level and run code before any workers or tasks get hatched.
see this for a slightly out-of-date (locust 0.9) example https://medium.com/locust-io-experiments/locust-experiments-feeding-the-locusts-cf09e0f65897.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You may want to try bringing in specifics from the sites referenced as the sites themselves may change or go away, which would make your answer useless.

Answer (score 0):

[Locust docs](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/running-locust-distributed.html#communicating-across-nodes) show this example:

```
@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs):
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, MasterRunner):
        environment.runner.register_message('test_users', setup_test_users)
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, WorkerRunner):
        environment.runner.register_message('acknowledge_users', on_acknowledge)
```

This is not directly useful for the OP's question but you can get to `environment.runner` via the User class. I used it as follows with Locust 2.5.1:

```
@events.test_stop.add_listener
def test_stop(**kw):
    if ('environment' in kw):
        if isinstance(kw['environment'].runner, MasterRunner):
            MySequentialTaskSet.print_stats()
```